# Graph initialized on every epoch after tensorflow upgrade

Tags: python, tensorflow, graph

i've been running my tensorflow code without any issues on TF2.4.
Meaning, the first epoch training was slow, from my understanding because the graph stuff was initialized.
After this, the following epochs were executing fast.
Now I upgraded to TF2.10 and on every epoch I get the message that the loop optimizer was skipped.
This is not the issue, just an indicator that the initial graph stuff is now executed with every epoch.
Therefore my training is now as slow for every epoch, like it was in the first epoch with TF2.4
Does anyone know why this happens, and how to fix it?

I tried to disable the grappler loop optimizer but it did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason:
I had memory leak problems in the past and created a Callback with a  tf.keras.backend.clear_session() call.
This seems to destroy the graph in TF2.10.